# Javascript - Radio buttons with switch case

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the div's background colour using inputs from the radio buttons but I struggle to change colours in reverse order e.g. (pink to black ) or (green to yellow). It works perfectly fine when I try to change colour in order e.g. (black to red) or (red to yellow). I have used console.log to check the variable when I click on a different radio button and it is changing accordingly.

Many thanks

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const cell = document.querySelector(".cell");
// var rows = 16; //default grid = 16x16
// var cols = 16;
var rows = 16;
var cols = 16;


function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--cols", cols);
  for (i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "cell";
    container.appendChild(cell).id = i + 1;
  };
};

function modifyCell() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var radioValue = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    switch (radioValue) {
      case 'black':
        // console.log(radioValue);
        $(".cell").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-black');
          })
          .on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-black');
          });
        break;
      case 'red':
        console.log(radioValue);
        $(".cell").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-red');
          })
          .on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-red');
          });
        break;
      case 'pink':
        console.log(radioValue);
        $(".cell").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-pink');
          })
          .on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-pink');
          });
        break;
      case 'yellow':
        console.log(radioValue);
        $(".cell").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-yellow');
          })
          .on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-yellow');
          });
        break;
      case 'green':
        console.log(radioValue);
        $(".cell").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-green');
          })
          .on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-green');
          });
        break;
      case 'blue':
        console.log(radioValue);
        $(".cell").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-blue');
          })
          .on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-blue');
          });
        break;
      case 'violet':
        console.log(radioValue);
        $(".cell").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-violet');
          })
          .on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('cell').addClass('cell-violet');
          });
        break;
      default:
        alert("!");
    };
  });
};

function reset() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    while (container.firstChild) {
      container.firstChild.remove();
    };
    makeGrid(rows, cols);
    modifyCell();
  });
};

function resetGrid() {
  rows = prompt('Enter a number for grid size. (min = 1, max = 50)');
  cols = rows;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    while (container.firstChild) {
      container.firstChild.remove();
    };
    makeGrid(rows, cols);
    modifyCell();
  });
};


makeGrid(rows, cols);
modifyCell();

$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  modifyCell();
});
```

```css
html {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, purple, pink);
  justify-items: center;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: purple;
  border: 5px thin purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 93vw;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  display: grid;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 3px solid purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vw;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.container .cell {
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container .cell:hover {
  background-color: hsl(30, 0%, 95%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-black {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-red {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-green {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-violet {
  background-color: violet;
  opacity: 1;
}

.button {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.button:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.radio {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
</head>
<header>
  Etch-a-Sketch
</header>

<body>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Reset Grid" onclick="resetGrid()">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="reset()">

  <div class="container">
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="black" name="colour" value="black" checked>
    <label for="black">Black</label>
    <input type="radio" id="red" name="colour" value="red">
    <label for="red">Red</label>
    <input type="radio" id="pink" name="colour" value="pink">
    <label for="pink">Pink</label>
    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="colour" value="yellow">
    <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
    <input type="radio" id="green" name="colour" value="green">
    <label for="green">Green</label>
    <input type="radio" id="blue" name="colour" value="blue">
    <label for="blue">Blue</label>
    <input type="radio" id="violet" name="colour" value="violet">
    <label for="violet">Violet</label>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So basically you want to control with the radio buttons which color a cell becomes when you click it. No matter if it is already filled in with a color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove all the other `cell-<color>` classes when adding the new color, not just the `cell` class.

You shouldn't add new event handlers every time the user selects a different radio button. Just have the event handler get the color from the selected radio button.

And instead of using `switch/case`, you can concatenate the button value to `cell-` to get the new class to add.

I'm not sure why you had both `mousedown` and `mouseup` handlers, since they both did the same thing. So I combined them into a single `click` handler.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const cell = document.querySelector(".cell");
// var rows = 16; //default grid = 16x16
// var cols = 16;
var rows = 16;
var cols = 16;


function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--cols", cols);
  for (i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "cell";
    container.appendChild(cell).id = i + 1;
  };
};

function modifyCell() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cell").on("click", function() {
      var radioValue = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
      $(this).removeClass("cell cell-black cell-red cell-pink cell-yellow cell-green cell-blue cell-violet").addClass("cell-" + radioValue);
    });
  });
}

function reset() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    while (container.firstChild) {
      container.firstChild.remove();
    };
    makeGrid(rows, cols);
    modifyCell();
  });
};

function resetGrid() {
  rows = prompt('Enter a number for grid size. (min = 1, max = 50)');
  cols = rows;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    while (container.firstChild) {
      container.firstChild.remove();
    };
    makeGrid(rows, cols);
    modifyCell();
  });
};


makeGrid(rows, cols);
modifyCell();
```

```css
html {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, purple, pink);
  justify-items: center;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: purple;
  border: 5px thin purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 93vw;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  display: grid;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 3px solid purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vw;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--cols), 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.container .cell {
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container .cell:hover {
  background-color: hsl(30, 0%, 95%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-black {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-red {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-green {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .cell-violet {
  background-color: violet;
  opacity: 1;
}

.button {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.button:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.radio {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
</head>
<header>
  Etch-a-Sketch
</header>

<body>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Reset Grid" onclick="resetGrid()">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="reset()">

  <div class="container">
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="black" name="colour" value="black" checked>
    <label for="black">Black</label>
    <input type="radio" id="red" name="colour" value="red">
    <label for="red">Red</label>
    <input type="radio" id="pink" name="colour" value="pink">
    <label for="pink">Pink</label>
    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="colour" value="yellow">
    <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
    <input type="radio" id="green" name="colour" value="green">
    <label for="green">Green</label>
    <input type="radio" id="blue" name="colour" value="blue">
    <label for="blue">Blue</label>
    <input type="radio" id="violet" name="colour" value="violet">
    <label for="violet">Violet</label>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar! It works perfectly now. I didn't know we could concatenate the button value when adding class.

Comment: When a function expects a string as an argument, it doesn't matter how you create the string.